# python - use while and for loop in json. why can't sort?

Tags: python, json

I'm wondering why sorting is not possible with for loop in json

If you use a for loop in python, it prints normally.

For example1

```
i = 0
while i < 3:
    for x in range(len(pname)):
        print(x)
    i += 1
```

For example2

```
from collections import OrderedDict


i = 0
while i < len_pnk:
    table = OrderedDict()
    channel_info["kind%s" % (i+1)] = pkind[i].text
    for x in range(4):
        table[time_list[x]] = x
    i += 1
```

The above examples show normal and accurate results.
but,

If the range (4) of the for statement in the second example is changed to 
range(len(var1)), it is outputted without sorting. (var1 is a temporary list)

For example3

```
from collections import OrderedDict


i = 0
while i < len_pnk:
    table = OrderedDict()
    channel_info["kind%s" % (i+1)] = pkind[i].text
    for x in range(len(pname)):
        table[time_list[x]] = x
    i += 1
```

example3's result = 
243, 217, 218, 219, 222 , 247, 224, 225, 226, 227,228,250,230,251 ...
time_list[x]'s result is output normally.

but, change

> table[time_list[x]] = x

=>

> table[x] = x / table[x] = time_list[x]

is normal.

Why is the result not sorted? 
thanks.

Comment: It’s not sorted because you haven’t sorted the items and  passed in the key to sort the values by `OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))`

Comment: It would have been really helpful if your example had been complete so we could run it on our own, but it's full of undefined variables like `time_list` and `channel_info`.

Comment: `OrderedDict` maintains the order of items added to the dict, so if they're not coming _out_ in sorted order, that means they weren't _added_ in sorted order.

Comment: Printing each item as it's added to the dict is an obvious first debugging step, and would have revealed your issue.  Did you try anything like that?